# Getting Warnings & Notices from Fresh WordPress 3.1.2 install

Tags: errors, warnings

I just installed WordPress 3.1.2, I got

> `Notice: automatic_feed_links is deprecated since version 3.0! Use add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' ) instead. in /works/web/elements/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3303

I also got an error about Cannot open stream or something about `wp-cron.php?doing-cron` or something

Its WordPress's own code, plus from a fresh install, this should not happen right?

**UPDATE**

The error I got was

> `Warning:
>   fopen(http://elements/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! in
>   /works/web/elements/wp-includes/class-http.php
>   on line 1063`

Running WordPress 3.1.2 fresh install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it sounds like even though its a fresh install of WP 3.1.2 that you are also using an existing theme that is using a deprecated function (you havent said so but im presuming),

if so paste this into your themes functions.php file (if your theme doesnt have one just create one and save it in your themes root folder)..

```
if(function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
add_theme_support('automatic-feed-links');
}
```

Comment: It's your Theme. The error message should be self-explanatory. Remove the `automatic_feed_links()` function from `functions.php`, and replace it with @Martin's code above.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Martin's answer: the `?doing-cron` error message is probably due to having `ALTERNATE_CRON` set to `true` in `wp-config.php`.

Comment: It can also be the cache enabled in a local install...

Comment: I dont see a `ALTERNATE_CRON` in my `wp-config.php` tho...

Comment: @kaiser, meaning this should only happen on localhost isit? But what cache are you talking about and how can I enable/disable it?

Comment: I updated my post with the error message in case u find it useful ...

Comment: Not absolut sure, but maybe: `define( 'WP_CACHE', true );` or `define( 'ENABLE_CACHE', true );`. I wrote "localhost", because i get this error from time to time, but only on my local install.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the wp_cron error by editing php.ini in my php installation.  Make sure you have **allow_url_fopen = On** and **allow_url_include = On**

Comment: Nothing in WordPress should neither of those to be set to true, and enabling these PHP config options **can introduce potential security vulnerabilities**. If you're using a Theme that requires either/both of these to be enabled, then I would suggest modifying the Theme, or finding a better Theme.